# Using ng-repeat with ng-include to create a recursive table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

I've done a bit of research around and I cannot seem to find the best pattern to use `ng-repeat` recursively to create a deep `table`. There is some noteworthy mentions [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3584) by user mgdelmonte regarding the subject, but alas, no solution.

**The HTML and template:**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myAppController">

<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item.html">
    <tr style="width:100%">        
        <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <div ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item.html'">

    </div>
</script>

<table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:30px;">Test</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="data in treeData" ng-include="'tree_item.html'">

    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

**The JS:**

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

function myAppController($scope) {
    $scope.treeData = [{
        "name": "Root",
        "nodes": [{
            "name": "Level 1",
            "nodes": [{
                "name": "Level 2"
            }]
        }]
    }];
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8f3rL/86/

This is the absolute farthest I got with it. It traverses the tree fine, but I'm losing the `<tr>` tags when it recurses down. Instead it's rendering `<span>`s.

My intuition is telling me that when the `ng-repeat` runs on that `<div>`, it is creating a separate scope for those `tr`s and `td`s, which I guess are illegal (since they have to be bound to a `table` element).

Changing the `div` to a `table` or `tbody` or `tr` is no-op as well (not that I'd even want to nest a table in like that).

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question, but you're doing ng-repeat with a `<tbody>` element. Is that legal? I expect a `<table>` to have exactly one `<tbody>`, but maybe I'm dumb :) Another silly question, what is a "deep table"?

Comment: Not dumb at all. The tbody and div inside a table are the problem.

Answer (score 6):

The browser doesn't like the multiple `tbody`s and the `div` tags between the rows. Try this...

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myAppController">

<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item.html">
    <td>{{data.name}}
        <table style="margin-left: 20px">
            <tr ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item.html'"></tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</script>

<table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:30px;">Test</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="width:100%" ng-repeat="data in treeData" ng-include="'tree_item.html'"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

[Live Demo - Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9a2Z/)

Comment: Yeah, good call on the `<div>` being inserted outside of the `<td>` ... and for being nice enough to provide a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this is still a bit unfortunate because we are nesting `table` elements. Consider what would happen if we placed a border on the tables... http://jsfiddle.net/V9a2Z/1/

Comment: Hi @Anthony I know it's beent a while but how would you do with a table with multiple `<th>`? Where would you place the `<table>` that contains the ng-include?